# Copy constructor is needed only in the case of dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So, if and only if we intend to allocate memory using `new`, we'll need user defined copy constructors?

What if we use a static array or `std::string`? 
The whole static array and `std::string` will be copied by the default copy constructor?

What about the file pointers? Memory isn't allocated there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *resource* is anything that you need to acquire and release explicitly.

A class that manages a resource will typically need a user-defined destructor, and consequently a user-defined (or deleted) copy-constructor and assignment-operator, and possibly move operations as well.

However, good design mandates the "single-responsibility rule", which says that every class should have one single responsibility and nothing more. Applying this rule means to wrap your resource into a class whose sole responsibility is to manage the resource, and which presents value- or value-like semantics to the outside.

Here's an example of opening a file using a resource-managing class:

```
if (auto fp = std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)>(std::fopen("/dev/null", "wb"),
                                                   std::fclose))
{
    std::fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp.get());
}
```

The use of the single-responsibility principle is that your code remains *local*, i.e. for every resource you have *one* line of code to take responsibility. If you had more than one, you often incur exponentially growing branching for error handling and multiple exit points. By contrast, single responsibility means you only have one place that you need to worry about for each resource.

Comment: I am not able to find specific answers to my questions in your answer. In case of files we don't allocate memory explicitly so is user defined copy constructor needed there?

Comment: @user462608: A file is a resource, just like memory. It's an example of a different resource, and is meant to demonstrate that you need to think more abstractly about the problem.